# Parsing XSD files does not work -> Cannot find any tags

Tags: python, parsing, xsd

I am currently trying to parse a XSD file in python using the lxml library.
For testing purposes I copied the following file together:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com" elementFormDefault="qualified">  
  <xs:element name="note">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
<xs:simpleType name="BaselineShiftValueType">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>The actual definition is
            baseline | sub | super | <percentage> | <length> | inherit 
            not sure that union can do this 
    </xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:restriction base="string"/>
 </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Now I tried to get the children of the root (schema), which would be: xs:element and xs:simpleType.
By iterating over the children of the root, everything works fine:

```
root = self.XMLTree.getroot()
for child in root:
    print("{}: {}".format(child.tag, child.attrib))
```

This leads to the output:

```
{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element: {'name': 'note'}
{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}simpleType: {'name': 'BaselineShiftValueType'}
```

But when I want to have only children of a certain type, it does not work:

```
root = self.XMLTree.getroot()
element = self.XMLTree.find("element")
print(str(element))
```

This gives me the following output:

```
None
```

Also using findall or writing `./element` or `.//element` does not change the result.
I am quite sure I am missing something. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the *namespace*. Unprefixed XPath selectors are considered as belonging to no namespace. You will have to register it with `register_namespace`:

```
self.XMLTree.register_namespace('xs',"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
```

and then use *prefixed* selectors to find your elements:

```
element = self.XMLTree.find("xs:element")
```

Comment: That would be a great thing if I knew the prefix and the namespace. But I have to handle abitrary schema files.
I found a quick fix to this problem on the site [link](http://bugs.python.org/issue18304) which just removes all the namespace things.

I am sorry I did not make this clear enough.

Comment: That's the XSD *standard* namespace, not the schema target namespace, so it shouldn't change (unless you are dealing with different kinds of XML Schemas, such as schematron for example). The target namespace you can get reading the `@targetNamespace` attribute from the `xs:schema` element.

Comment: And the prefix you register is arbitrary. It doesn't matter if in the original file it appears as `xsd` or if it's absent, as long as it's mapped to the namespace `"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`.

Answer (score 0):

To follow the [@helderdarocha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24210677/5222966), you can also define your namespace in a dictionary and use it in your search functions like in the [python xml.etree.ElementTree doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces):

```
ns = {'xs',"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"}
element = self.XMLTree.find("element", ns)
```